# Determinant and density of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Question: Let $X, Y$ be independent real valued random variables with the same density $f$ given by

$$
f(a)=C e^{-a^{2} / 2}
$$

where $C>0$ is such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(a) d a=1$. Define

$$
g:(0, \infty) \times[0,2 \pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2} \backslash\{0\},(r, \phi) \mapsto(r \cos (\phi), r \sin (\phi)) .
$$

Calculate $|\operatorname{det}(D g(r, \phi))|$. Also, let $R, \Phi$ be random variables with $g(R, \Phi)=$ $(X, Y)$. Find the density of $(R, \Phi)$, show that the density of $R$ is given by

$$
\begin{array}{r}
f_{R}(r)=2 \pi C^{2} r e^{-r^{2} / 2} \text { and calculate } C \text { from } \\
1=\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{R}(r) d r .
\end{array}
$$

---

My attempt: $(,)$ is a $2\times2$ matrix with entries: $\cos(\phi), \sin(\phi), -r\sin(\phi), r\cos(\phi)$.

I obtained this matrix by computing the derivatives of both parts of $g$ w.r.t. $r$ and $\phi$.

The determinant is, I think, $\cos(\phi)\cdot r\cos(\phi)-\sin(\phi)\cdot(-r\sin(\phi)) = r[\cos^{2}(\phi)+\sin^{2}(\phi)]= r$.

Comment: The problem is not tricky -- at least you can begin with by writing down what $Dg(r, \phi)$ is.

Comment: Can you start from the definition of the Jacobian to write down $Dg(r,\phi)$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong It is a 2x2 matrix with entries: cos(phi), sin(phi), -rsin(phi), rcos(phi).

Comment: @Enforce It is a 2x2 matrix with entries: cos(phi), sin(phi), -rsin(phi), rcos(phi).

Comment: Hoping that someone will now answer the question separately. They can have the bounty.

Comment: I've edited my question and have included my attempt and my progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then find out the joint density of $(X,Y)$

To do that use the independence condition to see that the joint density is the product of the marginals i.e. $$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)=C^{2}e^{-\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2}}$$

Now as the Jacobian determinant $|\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,\phi)}|=r$ as you have correctly determined then you can use this to get

$$f_{(R,\Phi)}(r,\phi)=C^{2}\cdot r\cdot e^{-\frac{r^{2}}{2}}\,,(r,\theta)\in[0,\infty)\times [0,2\pi)$$ .

Thus to find the marginal density of $R$, you integrate over $\phi$.

i.e. $$f_{R}(r)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} rC^{2}e^{-\frac{r^{2}}{2}}\,d\phi=2\pi\cdot C^{2} re^{-\frac{r^{2}}{2}}\,,r\in[0,2\pi)$$ .

Now integrate over $r$ and equate to $1$ to get the value of $C^{2}$.

i.e. $$\int_{0}^{\infty}2\pi C^{2}r e^{-\frac{r^{2}}{2}}\,dr =1$$ .

So substitute $\frac{r^{2}}{2}=z$ and get that

$$2\pi C^{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-z}\,dz = 1$$

And hence $C^{2}=\frac{1}{2\pi}$ and so $C=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$